# How to Ignore Bot Roles Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am coding a way to give a user every role in discord.py and im wondering if  there is a way to ignore bot roles for example:

```
@Eagle.command()
async def giveroles(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    roleappend = []
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        roleappend.append(role)
    await member.edit(roles=roleappend)
    await sendembed(ctx,"Give All Role",f"**Gave {member}**",roleappend)
```

It works fine but the one problem is it gives an error when the role is assigned to a bot. Any way around this error?

Comment: Why don't you simly use roles=ctx.guild.roles instead of copying the content into roleappend?

Answer (score 0):

You can get Role ids you want to ignore, check if with for loop then add to member.

```
@Eagle.command()
async def giveroles(ctx,member:discord.Member):
    roleappend = []
    ignored_roles = [ID1, ID2 ...]
    for role in ctx.guild.roles:
        if role.id not in ignored_roles:
            roleappend.append(role)

    await member.edit(roles=roleappend)
    await sendembed(ctx,"Give All Role",f"**Gave {member}**",roleappend)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a role is managed by an integration (meaning it cannot be assigned manually), you can check the [role's `managed` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Role.managed).

In your for loop, add an if statement that checks the `managed` attribute. If it is `False`, then append the role to your `roleappend` list.